# How can I make menus and submenus with links to the top 5 tags per section?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I'm trying to create a navigation structure with a main menu on the front page. Under each menu item there would be a link to the the top 5 tags used in that section. On clicking that section or one of the tags one would be taken to an article page where the list of tags for that entry would appear again - this time in full - in a side-bar.

Now, once the user is in a specific section I want any tag they add to their articles to be children of that specific section only. So for example if a use writes an article in the "book" section and adds the tag "thriller" his article should only appear under "books>>thriller" and not under "movies>>thriller".

Is this possible? Anyone has any tips on how I may do this?